# ajax request forces browser to reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm pretty new to ajax.

I try to load some data with Ajax and PHP. That basically works without any problems, but there is always a refresh bar when the Ajax updates are executed (in Firefox, Chrome).

The page isn't really refreshing entirely but every two seconds a refresh bar appears (and that gets really annoying): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ5XY.png

Code:

main.js:

```
    window.onload = function onLoad() {
        setInterval("reload()",2000);
    };
.
.
.
        function reload() {
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "script.php",
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#test").text("txt");
                }
            });
        }
```

The php Script just echos some txt!

Every help is appricated, Thank You!
Kind Regards

Comment: The `refresh bar` is a part of your code ?

Comment: Its working as expected. Page is not being reloaded!

Comment: Browser doesn't reload, your refresh bar is an third party library.. which you have included in you code.. never install software, which you don't know

Comment: well i will have to check that, a friend of mine just bought an admin template; maybe some code there is producing that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You guys were acutally right! Awesome!! Thank you so much :) Kind regards